# Get world space vertex coords using just combined WVP matrix

Tags: matrix, directx, shader

I have a third party app's trace  of DirectX 9 API calls with accessible parameters(but not have app source code), and there is used vertex shader with World_View_Projection matrix as single parameter. For some purpose I need to transform vertices from model to world space, so is there some way to do that using combined World_View_Projection matrix (dont have separate matrixes ) and may be with help of other data I can extract from raw API calls ? Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the world matrix as well as the world-view-projection matrix to your shader. You could of course pass the world matrix and a view-projection matrix, and do the multiply in your shader instead. Or you could pass world, view, and projection as individual matrices and create the combinations you need in the shader.

With modern Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 10.0 or later cards, they tend to have a lot of compute power so it's not as big a deal as it was on older Shader Model 2.0 cards to have the matrices precomputed before being passed to the shader.

> Why are you using Direct3D 9 instead of Direct3D 11? Unless you are targeting Windows XP, Direct3D 11 is a better choice all around. See the *DirectX Tool Kit* [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: I cannot modify logic, shaders etc because I have no source code - it is not my project, I've just captured DirectX API calls of running app with special tracing tool (apitrace), so I have to deal only with raw vertex data and API calls params such as that WVP matrix